# What do you call the soldiers who had the job to whip people's backs for their crimes?

Tags: word-request

I was watching passion of Christ and there's a scene when Jesus is whipped very badly before being crucified. I was wondering what you'd call one of those big brawny guys with the whip. Maybe **punishers**? **Whippers**? They can't be **executioners** can they?

Answer (score 2):

## It depends on the situation

### Executioner

> a resident executioner would also administer non-lethal physical punishments, or apply torture.

— [Wikipedia: Executioner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executioner)

This seems to be more of a full time job, where the local, well-trained executioner (who carried out a death sentence) would also carry out other punishments, possibly such as whipping or flogging.

### Inquisitor

> An inquisitor was an official (usually with judicial or investigative functions) in an Inquisition

— [Wikipedia: Inquisitor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inquisitor)

The inquisitor was more of an administrator in the room, while the people carrying out the actual torture may have been anyone operating under the inquisitor.

### (Jail) Torturer

These articles refer to the people who carried out the punishment as a "torturer":

[Working as a jail torturer ruined my life | Independent](https://www.independent.co.uk/news/world/europe/working-as-a-jail-torturer-ruined-my-life-6917392.html)

[What were the criteria for hiring torturers in medieval Europe? | Quora](https://www.quora.com/What-were-the-criteria-for-hiring-torturers-in-medieval-Europe)

Answer (score 2):

The Roman officials who carried out floggings were known as Lictors.

The [Encyclopedia Britannica definition](https://www.britannica.com/topic/lictor):

> **Lictor**, plural **lictors** or **lictores**, member of an ancient Roman class of magisterial attendants, probably Etruscan in origin and dating in Rome from the regal period. Lictors carried the [fasces](https://www.britannica.com/topic/fasces) for their magistrate and were constantly in his attendance in public; they cleared his way in crowds **and summoned and punished offenders for him**.

Comment: Worth noting that this word would not be known to the vast majority of English speakers.

Answer (score 1):

A few whipping-specific words come to mind: *flogger*, *scourger*, and *flagellator*, all nouns formed from verbs.

> **scourge** *v*
>   1. FLOG, WHIP
>   2a.  :to punish severely
>
> **flog** *v*
>   1a. : to beat with or as if with a rod or whip
>
> **flagellate** *v*
>   1. : WHIP, SCOURGE
>   2  : to drive or punish as if by whipping

<sub>Definitions from [Merriam-Webster Online](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary)</sub>

All have the additional benefit of being (ultimately) derived from Latin, the language of the Roman soldiers who did the scourging in that film.